# How do I keep my files when installing windows 7 on a storage partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

If there was already a copy of Windows installed on the partition I am trying to installing Windows, the files would go to a `Windows.old` folder. But will my files be there if there isn't one installed? Will it give me an option to keep them at all?

Creating another partition is not an option either since I'm at the max allowed: System Reserved, Recovery, Windows 10 and the drive i'm trying to install Windows 7 on.

Comment: You may be able to create a virtual hard disk for Windows 7,
by installing it to a VHD which can reside on any disk. For instructions, see the following references : - [Boot to a virtual hard disk: Add a VHDX or VHD to the boot menu](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-vhd--native-boot--add-a-virtual-hard-disk-to-the-boot-menu)
- [Dual-boot Windows 7 and Windows 8 using a VHD](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/dual-boot-windows-7-and-windows-8-using-a-vhd/)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you explicitly issue a "Format" command or other forms of deletion commands, installing Windows in a partition that already has files in it does not cause any data loss.

This is correct even if that partition already has folders called "Windows", "Program Files" and "ProgramData".

But please make sure you have backup first. Lots of things can go wrong when you don't have backup.

Answer (score 0):

Amusingly, the solution *is* to do a image backup, since a good many backup options are mountable

Assuming you have enough spare space, and don't plan to boot it off the same machine (there's a few known issues with that) [disk2vhd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd) would let you create an image (that's trivially and natively mountable in windows 7 or better) that would more or less appear as a new drive.

Alternatively you can set up a backup with most image backup software that excludes the location you save the image to (I used to use macrium reflect for that), and installing the backup software should let you mount and access the files off the backup as needed.

Both these alternatives give you a  "new" volume without needing to repartition, and backups never hurt.